# Using elasticsearch Java API

Tags: maven, elasticsearch

I am very new to elasticsearch. I found some simple java code for using elasticsearch:

```
import static org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.*;

// on startup

Node node = nodeBuilder().node();
Client client = node.client();

// on shutdown

node.close();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
package org.elasticsearch.node doesn't exist
```

Later, I found that I have put some information in `pom.xml`. What is that? How to make this simple program run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you know what Maven is?

I mean that if you are using Maven, then you need to add `elasticsearch-VERSION.jar`
 as a dependency in [your pom.xml](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/_maven_repository.html).

If not, then you need to add elasticsearch jar in your project classpath and some other libs such as (it depends of elasticsearch version you are using):

- antlr-runtime-3.5.jar
- asm-4.1.jar
- asm-commons-4.1.jar
- jna-3.3.0.jar
- jts-1.12.jar
- log4j-1.2.17.jar
- lucene-analyzers-common-4.6.0.jar
- lucene-codecs-4.6.0.jar
- lucene-core-4.6.0.jar
- lucene-expressions-4.6.0.jar
- lucene-grouping-4.6.0.jar
- lucene-highlighter-4.6.0.jar
- lucene-join-4.6.0.jar
- lucene-memory-4.6.0.jar
- lucene-misc-4.6.0.jar
- lucene-queries-4.6.0.jar
- lucene-queryparser-4.6.0.jar
- lucene-sandbox-4.6.0.jar
- lucene-spatial-4.6.0.jar
- lucene-suggest-4.6.0.jar
- spatial4j-0.3.jar

I'd recommend to use Maven because it's much easier to deal with dependencies.

Hope this helps